# digits 0 to 9 in a triangle

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

I need help with a task in my intro to python programming course that requires a code that will print the following using two 'for-loops', one being nested:

```
0

0 1

0 1 2

0 1 2 3

0 1 2 3 4

0 1 2 3 4 5

0 1 2 3 4 5 6

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

So far i have come up with the following code, but my triangle of numbers begins at the digit 1 instead of 0:

```
for i in range(-1,9):
    print ('\n')
    for i in range (int(i+1)):
        j = i+1
        print (j, end=' ')
```

Can anyone advise what I should do to make my list of digits begin from 0 instead of 1? Also any suggestions on how to make my code more readable? Thanks.

Comment: In your second `for` loop, you are adding 1 to `j` *before* you print `j`. Switch those lines and you should be all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `range`, if you want the last integer to be included, you need to add one.  With this in mind, I think the following makes sense:

```
for i in range(9+1):  # +1 since you want the loop to include 9
    for j in range(i+1):  # +1 since you want your print to include i
        print (j, end=' ')
    print ('\n')
```

The `print(\n)` statement can go before or after your `j` for-loop, although the output will be slightly different.  (Maybe because I'm used to mechanical typewrites, I think of `\n` as finishing a line rather than getting ready for a new one, but both are reasonable.)

I don't like the idea of starting at `-1` so you can then add `1` later.  It's unduly complicated, and a bad habit to start with as a beginner.

Comment: Thank you tom10! I understand the advice and totally agree I have made things more complicated in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your code structure, the following will work:

```
for i in range(-1, 10): # you need 10 so that the triangle goes up to 9
    print("\n")
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print(j, end=" ")
```

Result:

```
0 

0 1 

0 1 2 

0 1 2 3 

0 1 2 3 4 

0 1 2 3 4 5 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Change `print("\n")` to  `print("line \n")` and you will see that two empty lines are printed at the beginning ...